# Can visual studio automatically indent / format preprocessing directives?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force indentation of C# conditional directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321228/how-to-force-indentation-of-c-sharp-conditional-directives)

Say I want to type this in Visual Studio:

```
    class Program
    {
        private const Byte NUM_THREADS =
        #if DEBUG
            1;
        #else
            8;
        #endif
    }
```

If I simply type it out (i.e. not manually fix any indentation), Visual Studio will format it like this:

```
    class Program
    {
        private const Byte NUM_THREADS =
#if DEBUG
 1;
#else
        8;
#endif
    }
```

Is there anything I can do so it automatically indents so it looks like the first example?

Comment: What do you mean by "simply type it out"? Do you have some kind of auto-formatting mode turned on?

Comment: @GregHewgill I mean typing and only adding new lines myself, but not pressing tab to add any manual indentation.

Comment: Visual Studio Tools | Option => Text Editor => C# => Formatting has a large number of options, but it looks like pre-processor definitions are always hung to the left (except for #region).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to have preprocessor commands follow the code indentation. Wish it did though. :(

It looks like the reason is previous compilers barfed at spaces that appeared before the commands, according to: [Indenting #defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789073/indenting-defines)

Answer (score -3):

Go to **`Edit menu => Format Document`** OR Press short cut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (In short <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
This short cut you can use .html, .aspx. .cs etc...

Comment: Have you tried it with pre-processor directives?

Comment: Auto-format does *not* work on preprocessor commands. It works on everything else.

Comment: Except it *does* work on `#region` for some annoying reason, at least in VS 2017.