# How to indent C# conditional directives using ReSharper StyleCop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, stylecop, preprocessor-directive

My goal is being able to indent preprocessor statements ***#if*/*#endif*** the same way I can indent ***#region*/*#endregion*** statements in the Visual Studio text editor.

I am aware that there are several similar questions on SO about this, mostly old ones, but none actually show how to write a ReSharper 2017 ***StyleCop*** rule which would achieve ***#if*/*#endif*** indentation.

So, could anyone provide a working solution to this?

**Edit:**
*I want the formatted (indented) directives code to look similar to the one in the selected snippet:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the question.

Comment: Just StyeCop installed through ReSharper extensions: https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop.ReSharper

Comment: Does `indent-preproc-block` (http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html) do what you want?

Comment: I want something that works with ReSharper's "Silent Cleanup Code" command. The tool you're indicating seems to be a commandline application that doesn't integrate with VisualStudio/ReSharper.

Comment: ReSharper does not have such a feature, unfortunately.

Comment: I am aware f that, but several answers in regard to the same issue indicate the StyleCop for ReSharper could be configured to format those keywords.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092271/how-to-indent-if-directives-in-code ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321228/how-to-force-indentation-of-c-sharp-conditional-directives

Comment: The closest I can see to a solution from those 'answers' is  http://www.lovethedot.net/2008/05/creating-custom-rules-for-microsoft.html .  Did you give that a try?

Comment: That's a post from 2008, I don't think it applies to ReSharper's StyleCop of 2017.

Comment: You said some posts said StyleCop for ReSharper could be configured to solve your problem. I read those posts and that link was the only 'solution' I found there. If that wasn't what you were referring to, what were you referring to?